# A pair of parallel sides for a convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral, and let $M$ be the midpoint of side $CD$.

Suppose lines $BM$ and $AM$ are perpendicular to each other and that $AB = BC + AD$.

Show that $BC$ is parallel to $AD$.

[image: convex quadrilateral]

Comment: @hardmath, yeah of course, thanks for the suggestions. But I'm unable to think of how to write it in a concise form in the title; could you help?

Comment: @hardmath yeah no problem.

Comment: I added a quick sketch of a convex quadrilateral, one that does not particularly support the desired conclusion.  Please review and let me know what you think.

Comment: I think it's pretty good; although the square indicating the right angle can be placed more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Reflect point $B$ in line $AM$ and let the image of $B$ under this reflection be $B^*$. Then triangles $ABM$ and $AB^*M$ are congruent so $AB = AB^*$ and $\angle AMB = \angle \, AMB^* = 90^{\circ}$. The latter equality between the two angles implies that point $M$ lies on the segment $BB^*$. Furthermore $MB = MB^*$ (because of the reflection) and $MC = MD$ (by assumption) as well as $\angle \, BMC = \angle \, DMB^*$ (since $B, M, B^*$ are collinear) which implies that triangles $BMC$ and $B^*MD$ are congruent. Consequently, $DB^* = BC$ and $\angle \, DBM = \angle \, CBM$. Look at triangle $ADB^*$. In that triangle $AD + DB^* = AD + BC = AB = AB^*$ which holds if and only if the point $D$ lies on the segment $AB^*$. Consequently, $$\angle \, AB^*B = \angle \, DBM =  \angle \, CBM = \angle \, CBB^*$$ which holds if and only if $AB^*$ and $BC$ are parallel. Since point $D$ lies on $AB^*$, the segments $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel.